# cakePHP renaming Database names

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have spend hours trying to find where this issue is.

I have a database called `tapplicant` with a corresponding `TapplicantController` and `Tapplicant` model.

The View folder is called `Tapplicant`.

When ever i query e.g : `$count = $this->Tapplicant->find()`
It always looks for database table 'tapplicants' , it adds a 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to say you have a *table* name tapplicants, not a database.

By default, Cakephp uses the plural form of the model name. If you need to change the table name, use [useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable).

In your Tapplicant model:

```
public useTable = 'tapplicant';
```